# How do I set up a dynamic character counter for different inputs and textareas on the same page with different max lengths on each one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, counter, maxlength

I have a product page that has multiple text inputs and one textarea input. 3 text inputs have a maxlength of 18, 1 text input has a maxlength of 5, and 1 textarea has a maxlength of 255. How do I set up character counters for each element without writing multiple functions?

I've set up a basic function that changes the character counter html from the value of the .form-input, but obviously that applies it to all the counters. I'm having trouble with specifying it to each individual input and textarea.

```html
<div class="form-field text-lines" data-product-attribute="input-text">
    <label class="form-label form-label--inlineSmall" for="attribute_text_347">Text Line 1:</label>
    <p id="text-info">Type exactly as you want the text to appear, including upper/lower case.</p>

    <input class="form-input form-input--small" type="text" id="attribute_text_347" name="attribute[347]" maxlength="18">
    <span class="characters-left">Characters Left: <span class="counter">18</span></span>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let text_max = 18;
    $('.counter').html(text_max);

    $('.text-lines .form-input').keyup(function() {
        let text_length = $('.text-lines .form-input').val().length;
        let text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('.counter').html(text_remaining);
    });
});
```

I expect each input/textarea's character counter to update while typing in that specific input/texarea.

Comment: Define `text_max` inside the event, and instead of hardcoding `18`, retrieve the element's `maxlength`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have this:

```
let text_length = $('.text-lines .form-input').val().length;
let text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
```

I think what you really want is

```
let text_length = this.value.length;
let max_length = this.getAttribute("maxlength");
let text_remaining = max_length - text_length;
```

Don't do another jquery to get the text length, and get the max length attribute for the input element

Comment: Thanks! All I needed to change after your help was this line. 
$(this).next('.characters-left').find('.counter').html(textRemaining);

Answer (score 1):

I used Your code to be more functional. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const inputs = $('.form-input');
  inputs.each(function(index, element){
    inputLengthCounter($(element).attr('id'));
  });
});

function inputLengthCounter(input_id) {
  const input = document.getElementById(input_id);
  const text_max = input.maxLength;
  const counter = $(input).next('.characters-left').find('.counter');
  $(counter).html(text_max);

  $(input).keyup(function() {
    let text_length = $(this).val().length;
    let text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $(counter).html(text_remaining);
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o20q79n8/

It run function inputLengthCounter for each input that have an id and maxlength attribute.